# WordPress WP_Query with comma separated Strings

Tags: wordpress, rest, custom-fields

I created a custom field with key 'director' for every post. One post has the value `Joe Russo`, 
another post `Joe Russo, Anthony Russo`.
I'm trying to filter all posts by `Joe Russo` and want to find the titles of both posts. I want it to work for any name, given that they will always be separated by a comma. I tried the following:

```
$args = array(
            'meta_key'   => 'director',
            'meta_value' => 'Joe Russo',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );

$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query($args);
if($meta_query->have_posts()) {
    $titles = array();

    while($meta_query->have_posts()) {
        $meta_query->the_post();
        $titles[] =  get_the_title();
    }
    return $titles;
} else {
    return 'No posts found';
}
```

But that will only find the one with `Joe Russo` . I also fiddled with REGEXP as the compare method but couldn't get it working.
Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: This part of the documetation states that `meta_compare` also allows "REXEXP" as a value for a string comparison: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters So maybe you can use `meta_compare`

Comment: As an aside, this sounds like "Director" would make better sense as a [custom Taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/), with the terms being "Joe Russo", "Anthony Russo", "Billybob Russo", etc. This is almost a text book example of hen a taxonomy makes more sense than a meta field, not to mention that comparative meta queries are inherently slower on large sites.

Answer (score 1):

As Johannes pointed out, I mistakenly used `compare` instead of `meta_compare`. This works fine:

```
$args = array(
            'meta_key'   => 'director',
            'meta_value' => 'Joe Russo',
            'meta_compare' => 'LIKE',
        );
```

Though I will probably replace this and use taxonomies instead, see comment from Xhynk.